# How do I read a .csv file into a GCP Dataflow and then get the count for a specific column and write it to BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, pipeline, apache-beam

I need to read a csv file into DataFlow that represents a table, perform a GroupBy transformation to get the number of elements that are in a specific column, and then write that number to a BigQuery table along with the original file.

So far I've gotten the first step - reading the file from my storage bucket and I've called a transformation, but I don't know how to get the count for a single column since the csv has 16.

```
public class StarterPipeline {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StarterPipeline.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create());

    PCollection<String> lines = p.apply("ReadLines", TextIO.read().from("gs://bucket/data.csv"));
    PCollection<String> grouped_lines = lines.apply(GroupByKey())

    PCollection<java.lang.Long> count = grouped_lines.apply(Count.globally())

    p.run();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you specify better the count that you want to do?

Comment: Another way of doing this is to write the file to BigQuery as is, and then just write a single SQL statement to get the count and save it as a table. Much easier than writing `GroupBy` etc. Do you _have_ to use Dataflow for everything?

Comment: @GrahamPolley Great alternative. In addition, are you aware which  key are you using in your group by key? I recommend you to split your CSV line and to build a KV element, with the key that you want, and the V the line.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading whole lines from your CSV to a PCollection on strings. That's most likely not enough for you.

What you want to do is to

1. Split whole string into multiple strings relevant to columns
2. Filter PCollection to values that contain something in required column. [1]
3. Apply Count [2]

[1] https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Filter.html
[2] https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Count.html

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you convert that csv into suitable form. For Eg: Convert it into TableRow and then perform GroupByKey based. This way you can identify the column respective to particular value and find the count based on that.